# python ma-in-the-middle scapy and netfilterqueue

Tags: python, scapy, netfilter

I am trying to use scapy to perform man-in-the-middle attack on the LAN spoofing the MAC address of my gateway on one side and my smartphone on the other. This part goes on well. However, I would like to modify packets on the fly as well. Hence I am using `iptables` and `netfilterqueue` module of python. After working for a short time, the modify script does not print any packets even if traffic is still getting spoofed :

Here is the iptables rule added for `PREROUTING` traffic:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.10/32 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
```

Here is the script used to `bind` on the queue 1 :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *
from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue

def modify(packet):
   print(packet.get_payload())
   pkt = IP(packet.get_payload())
   print('source:'+pkt.src+'destination:'+pkt.dst)
   # packet.set_payload(str(pkt))
   packet.accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   try:
      nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
      nfqueue.bind(1, modify)
      nfqueue.run()
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
      nfqueue.unbind()
```

Symptoms : even if man-in-the-middle goes on well, and the nfqueue script prints packet for a short time, nothing seems to go on the netfilter queue after a few seconds and nothing goes printed by the modify script anymore.

If I set the source IP address for the whole subnet instead in the `iptables` rule, I can get broadcast and multicast packets printed in the script. However, not the traffic from my smartphone.

I know I could use `ettercap` to perform such task, however I would like to create it myself to make sure I understand thinks clearly (and obviously this is not the case by now).

Many thanks for your help!